# Relationship between the altitude of an isosceles triangle and segments drawn to the lateral side from a point on the base.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Question :In an isosceles triangle, the sum of the distances from each point of the base to the lateral sides is constant.

I've tried a couple of things, but it seems like this statement is not true. Can someone provide a HINT towards a solution of the problem, if any? I don't want an answer I just want a minor hint that will guide me.

Comment: Playing around with Geogebra, it appears to be true. So you'll have to find an explanation for why it's so. As a hint, try focusing on the triangles formed by the segments drawn to the laterals from your point on the basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose you have an isosceles triangle $\Delta ABC$ with base $\overline{BC}$. Then you can draw a second isosceles triangle $\Delta A'BC$ by reflecting $A'$ across $\overline{BC}$, so that $ABA'C$ is a parallelogram. Now draw a line which intersects $\overline{BC}$ and is perpendicular to $AB$. This line is divided into two segments by $\overline{AB},\overline{BC},$ and $\overline{A'B}$. Can you see a relationship between these segments and your question?

Comment: If it's not clear, I can include a diagram; but I would strongly suggest the reader attempt this themselves first!

Comment: Yes, it very clear! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Glad it helped. (I originally did it using similarity of triangles, but once I spotted that way of looking at it I knew that's what I should post.) @mathsundergrad